# iText html string to .rtf file

Tags: java, itext

I want to convert an html string to a .rtf file. when i do something like this.

```
Document doc = new Document();
RtfWriter2.getInstance(doc, out);
HtmlParser hp = new HtmlParser();
hp.go(doc, in);
```

I get an exception saying:

```
<ExceptionConverter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Users\ddarellis.OTS\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain\resources\images\thyreos.jpg 
(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

This because i have an image inside html can the path is relative.

Is there a way to set the basepath or a way to do my job?

Comment: Did you copy the path and actually check that the file is there?

Comment: As @LaurentiuL. said, check the file at that path. Though you used relative path, it is resolved to that absolute path as mentioned in the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your HtmlParser. The parser should check the source attributes for relative paths and supplement them with the site host. Then you can download the images seperatly from the HTML DOM tree.